# IOS 10 Issue: Changing App language is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

I was working on an app, in which we change the language within the app by using following code

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[@"ar"]forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

But since the IOS 10 update this code is not working, I mean iPhone's language remain the default one.

Comment: means your `NSUserDefaults` is not updating ? and if you have only one value then why you setting object as `array`, you should use string instead!